# how to buffer and delay printf() output?

Tags: c, file-io, io, buffer, printf

I wrote a `C` program and in the program there are many printf() which output log information to stdout. Now I want to use multiple processes to run the program simultaneously with different arguments. And I want to redirect the output from stdout to a log file using `>`.
But multiple processes are running at the same time, their log information output overlap with each other, which can be confusing for future analysis.

one solution is: considering that different processes will exit at different time,modify the C program, so each log information is temporarily written into a temporal file. When the C program is about to exit. Read from the temporal file and write the content to stdout, this requires a lot of modification.

My idea is:  I hope in the C program, all the printf() output can be buffered, the outputs put into stdout/redirection only when the process exits.

is it possible or not?
thanks!

Comment: just redirect every process to a different log file and append them afterwards to a common file

Comment: On which operating system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really possible, unless you are sure that the output is reasonably bounded (e.g. the total output is less than a few megabytes), otherwise use a logging mechanism which send to some central logger (like `syslog`).

On Linux and most Posix systems, the simplest way to do logging would be to use [syslog(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/syslog.3.html) which is designed for logging (and is able to deal with different processes). I think this is the preferable approach.

With GNU libc, you could consider using [open_memstream(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fmemopen.3.html) -to write to memory, and here you need to be sure the total output is bounded- and use [atexit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/atexit.3.html) to have the memory stream written at the exit of the program into some file; you probably want to use some locking mechanism like [flock(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/flock.2.html) etc...

As commented by [J.Holetzeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2176756/j-holetzeck) the simplest way is to redirect output into different files (perhaps using [freopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/freopen.3.html), or simply in the invoking shell), and later merge these files.

<sup>I'm guessing you use Linux, or some Posix system. For Windows, I have no idea.</sup>